# assetic:dump doesn't dump all assets

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

I run the following 3 commands after I deploy my app in production:

```
php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug --no-warmup
```

The latter one outputs the following:

[image]

However in browser nothing loads up:

[image]

Also, this is what the css folder looks like:

[image]

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

clear cache first before assetic dump:
`php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod
php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug --no-warmup
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod --no-debug`

Comment: Same thing. It didn't work until I ran hp bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev in production.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the following command resolved the issue:

```
php bin/console assetic:dump --env=dev
```

Not sure why since it's in production but it worked.